# How to match different groups with different positions with one single pattern in Python3 Regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I want to match different groups with different positions with one pattern only.

> notice the last 5 digits are in different position, this is my actual inquiry.

```
import re
  line = "Jul 6 14:02:08 computer.name jam_tag=psim[29187]: (UUID:006)"
  pattern = r"(Jul\s\d\s\d+:+\d+:+\d+)" # but I coudn't recognize how to match another group with different position which is the 5 digits between brackets

  result = re.search(pattern, line)  
  print(result) # output should be:    Jul 6 14:02:08 29187
                # my actual output:   Jul 6 14:02:08    I still don't know how to match a group with different position using one pattern only
```

Comment: Sorry, your test strings are far from `Hello world 9 Jul hello WORLD [12345]`. What are the pattern requirements?

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/78vL5b

Comment: Hi Mr.Wiktor. I hope you are doing well. I edited it, heopefully it is clear to understand what I mean. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, no, please explain the rules.

Comment: I am really sorry for wasting your time. Please accept my excuse. What I want is well explained in the homework code with the function def show_time_of_pid(line)

Comment: https://ideone.com/L7gic4 ?

Comment: I made it simpler Mr.Wiktor. Please accept my sorry for annoying you with unclear text and code. Consider me as your student. Thank you very much for helping me for free.

Comment: ideone.com/L7gic4  exactly Mr.Wiktor. Post it as code Please so I can click solved. I am very thankful to your modesty and help. Thank you very much. My Respectful Regards.

Comment: strange, i see 0 upvotes

Comment: You just do not have enough rep to see them, https://imgur.com/a/gBmj7Qq. Do you see the Timeline icon below the down arrow? If yes, click it and the go to *Show vote Summaries*

Comment: ok MR. Wiktor, thank you. You are such a beautiful human being and always ready to help. RESPECT.

Comment: Well, sometimes I sleep :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
def show_time_of_pid(line):
  pattern = r"^(Jul\s+\d+\s+[\d:]*\d).*?\[(\d+)]"
  result = re.search(pattern, line)  
  return "{} pid:{}".format(result.group(1),result.group(2)) if result else ""
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hfYW4d/1).

**Regex details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(Jul\s+\d+\s+[\d:]*\d)` - Group 1: `Jul`, 1+ whitespaces, 1+ digits, 1+ whitespaces, zero or more digits or colons and then a digit
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\[(\d+)]` - `[`, Group 2 capturing 1 or more digits, and then a `]`.

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/L7gic4):

```
print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:01:23 computer.name CRON[29440]: USER (good_user)")) 
# => Jul 6 14:01:23 pid:29440
print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:02:08 computer.name jam_tag=psim[29187]: (UUID:006)"))
# => Jul 6 14:02:08 pid:29187
```

Comment: Please upvote if you find my question relevant. Thanks.